# Use Wicket properties in Enums directly

Tags: java, properties, enums, wicket

I have an Enum that looks like this:

```
package de.test;

public enum TestEnum {
    bar("Test");

    private final String label;

    private TestEnum(String labelName) {
        this.label = labelName;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

I want to store the string "Test" in a Java properties file. The enum "TestEnum" should store the properties key and its "getLabel" method should lookup the appropriate value in the properties file and return this value.

```
package de.test;

public enum TestEnum {
    bar("test.key");

    private final String label;

    private TestEnum(String labelKey) {
       this.label = labelKey;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        // Look up properties value with label as key in the according properties file
        String labelValue = ...
        return labelValue;
    }
}
```

And I have a properties file that looks like this:

```
test.key=Test
```

The background of this question is: I have a Wicket Component, let's say a label and the value of the label is stored in this enum. But the enum should not hold the used string, instead it should just hold the key for the properties file. The solution to return the properties key to the Wicket Component and to let the Component lookup the value in the appropriate properties file is not practical in my situation.

I use Wicket 6.17 and Java 8.

Thanks for tips.

Edit: Intention of this question:
The usage of an enum in this context is owed to an old architecture that may not be changed. On the other hand there exists a request that this enum is not allowed to hold the concrete string for the label, because all strings used in the GUI have to be exported to a properties file.

Another intetion for me is to learn if this is even possible to make an enum use a properties file, maybe with help of the Wicket framework.

Comment: 1. Give compilable code (at least first enum). 2. Maybe I don't understand this question, maybe You java enum's. Eventually if we build compilable code, enum will be initialised only once by first classloading - is this Your goal? Seem You break java enum philosophy

Comment: Compilation errors, runtime exceptions (with stacktrace) are for programmer, if Yoy don't include, You lost chance to professional anwser

Comment: Wicket model philosophy is misunderstood too, example has nothing to wicket/model

Comment: Editted my question to make it hopefully more specific. Thanks for suggestions. Edit: I tested the first code snippet and it is compilable.

Comment: OK. After redaction is better. Everything You write is "typical" except enum. Why enum? Here is canonical documentation (do not be afraid with "internalisation" word, for single language substitution too) https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Everything+about+Wicket+internationalization

Comment: I know this source already, but the usage of an enum in this context is owed to an old architecture that may not be changed. On the other hand there exists a request that this enum is not allowed to hold the concrete string for the label, because all strings used in the GUI have to be exported to a properties file. I added this comment to the question. I know that the usage of the enum in this context makes it more complex than it should be. The intetion of this question is on the otherhand to learn if this is even possible for enums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  #getLabel ()  do `Application.get ().getLocalizer ().getString(key)`.

P.S. for the bad formatting. I'm in my mobile device.

Comment: Due to the Wicket api doc for version 6.x there is no method "getLocalizer()" in class "Application". Can you specify which method you mean?

Comment: wicket api doc: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/Application.html

Comment: App.getResourceSettings ().getLocalizer

Answer (score 0):

```
private TestEnum(String labelKey) {
       this.label = KinfOfPropertyLoader(labelKey); // probably static
    }
```

BUT ho many "items" has Your list? enum has constant set of values ("items") usually small. GUI has big and growing list.

Comment: In this case the enum has just two items.

Comment: Two bad controlled strings for so much invention? Probably I'm too old :(

Answer (score 0):

If im getting this right, you want to pass an enum variable to a `Label` and let the label grab the i18n value for the enums value?

```
TestEnum somevar = TestEnum.bar;
add(new Label("label", somevar));
```

Have a look at the `EnumLabel` class and override it's getResource method:

```
@Override
protected String resourceKey(TestEnum value) {
    return value.getValue();
}
```

It'll use the Enums value to determine the property key to use.